# mounting wd my cloud in raspbian fails

Tags: raspberry-pi, mount, raspbian, nfs, nfsclient

I try to mount a folder of my wd my cloud NAS in raspbian, but I always get Permission denied.

What I've done:

Adding folder on my cloud to /etc/exports

```
/nfs/raspberry 192.168.178.26(rw,subtree_check)
```

then

```
service nfs-kernel-server restart
exportfs -a
```

On client showmount -e 192.168.178.23 shows

```
/nfs           *
/nfs/raspberry 192.168.178.26
```

Then trying to mount and test:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o v3,rw,soft,nolock,wsize=8192,rsize=16384 192.168.178.23:/nfs/raspberry nas/
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls nas
ls: cannot open directory nas: Permission denied
```

It shows that I don't have permission to `/nfs/raspberry`.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've added the folder I want to mount with the WD GUI,
when I add the folder by ssh and set its owner/group to root/share and then adding folder to /etc/exports it works fine.